# How to export a function from one file to another on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

a piece of my function

```
var Foo = function(dir, pathToFile){
    let Mode = require('stat-mode'); // проверка дириктори или файл
    let temp; //вспомогательная переменная 
    let jsonFile = { 
        table: []
     };
..............
}
```

I do the export as follows

```
module.exports = Foo;
```

and import like this

```
const foo = require("../index.js");
```

call

```
foo(dir, 'data/firstScreen.json');
```

as a result I get this error

```
foo(dir, 'data/firstScreen.json');
TypeError: foo is not a function
```

Comment: did you try `import foo from '../index'`?

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you've imported the right module? And that `Foo` had the correct value when assigning it to `module.exports` (is that the only code in that file)?

Comment: not sure. How can I check this?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9sAqN878 index.js
https://pastebin.com/ap9PKZYN  routes.js

Comment: `module.exports` is required to be an object.

Comment: @RandyCasburn — (a) Functions are objects (b) `module.exports` is not required to be an object

Comment: @Quentin - (deferring the function thing) and with respect - here is the ground truth on what NodeJS _expects_ module.exports to be: [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) - I'm only disagreeing with you because the documentation does.

Comment: Tests with a number show it works in practise. Functions are definitely objects though.

Comment: @ЕфимМаргин — As Begi said, it should work.

Comment: @Quentin I sent my code, maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `index.js` is in the parent directory of `routes.js`

Comment: @RandyCasburn how can I make sure of this?

Comment: From the code you posted on pastebin (please [edit] your question instead) it looks like you have a circular dependency between your modules. Don't have them require each other.

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately, I don't understand how to fix it. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @Bergi The problem is that I do export from roures.js?
But if I remove this, my code stops working.....